# re-calculate every sum total of every row when radio change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day,

I have a dynamic table where you can add and remove table when you press X button, in each row there is a Current Qty field and Adjusted Qty field and also there is a New Qty field which is derived when you input a number on the Adjusted Qty Field, and its all working correctly but I want to add a functionality that will change every total Qty Field base on checked radio box above the table. Like if you click the IN (radio button), the operation will be ADD, and if you click the OUT (radio button), the operation will be MINUS and all the rows should be affected by every 'onchange' event of the radio button. Can anyone please help me :)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="box">                                    
                <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                    <div id="records">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="departments">Department</label>
                            <select name="departments" id="">
                            @foreach($departments as $department)
                            <option value="{{$department->xid}}">{{$department->department}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <label for="radio">Adjustment Type</label>
                          <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" class="adjType" value="in" id="radioIn" name="optradio">Inventory In</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" class="adjType" value="out" id="radioOut" name="optradio">Inventory Out</label>
                          </div>
                          </div>

<label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
<input type="text" name="remarks" required id="memo" placeholder="Text input" class="form-control">
<br>  

<table class="table table-condensed" id="adjustmentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Item</th>
      <th width="10%">Qty on Hand</th>
      <th width="10%">Adjusted Qty</th>
      <th width="10%">new Qty</th>
      <th width="10%">Current Cost</th>
      <th width="10%">Adjusted Cost</th>
      <th width="10%">Cost Diff</th>
      <th width="10%">Expiration Date</th>
      <th width="10%">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>10.40</td>
      <td>12.00</td>
      <td>.60</td>
      <td>11/21/1016</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 31</td>
      <td>230</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>246</td>
      <td>31.40</td>
      <td>20.00</td>
      <td>-11.40</td>
      <td>11/21/1019</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 6</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>22.40</td>
      <td>30.00</td>
      <td>7.60</td>
      <td>11/21/1016</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var $this = $(document);

$this.on("change",'input[name="optradio"]',function(){
var rowCount = $('#adjustmentTable tr').length - 1;
});
```

Comment: What part isn't working? A demo would help in jsfiddle.net or other code share site. Much simpler to help when we can interact with the code

Comment: Hello @charlietfl Thank you for stopping by! when I click the radio button, I want every new Input row will be recalculated base on the option I choose, if its an Inventory IN ( the operation should be ADDITION) and if its an Inventory Out ( should be subtraction) but I dont know how to achieve this functionality,

Comment: Put the html into a demo...seems like your `if` should be doing what you want just glancing at the code

Comment: Hi @charlietfl sorry I cant make it to work on jsfiddle but I added the code above

Comment: Can you at least provide source html instead of server template...easy to copy from browser

Comment: Hello @charlietfl I simplified the html into a basic one... and added a little JS below it that detects when my radio button is changed.. I Hope it would be simplier to look at now.. thanks alot for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create event handlers for the "change" event on those radio buttons.  These event handlers will then loop through all the rows of your table, and apply the AutoCalculateDifference function to each row.  Something like this:

```
$("#radioIn, #radioOut").change(function() {
    // The user clicked a radio button.  Now loop through all the 
    // rows in the table.  NOTE:  You should be more specific with
    // this jQuery selector to refer to the exact ID of the table.
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        autoCalculateDifferenceOnRow(this);
    });
});
```

If you do this, then you will need to refactor your AutoCalculateDifference function a little bit to be able to handle an incoming parameter representing the row, rather than always using "this".  For example,

```
function autoCalculateDifferenceOnRow(currentRow) {

    if(document.getElementById('radioIn').checked) {
        var type = 1;
    }else if(document.getElementById('radioOut').checked) {
        var type = 0;
    }

    var $adjQty = $(currentRow).find('.adjQty');
    var $newCost = $(currentRow).find('.newCost');
    var $onHandQty = $(currentRow).find('p.onHandQty');
    var $qtyDiff = $(currentRow).find('p.qtydiff');
    var $currentCost = $(currentRow).find('p.currentCost');
    var $costDiff = $(currentRow).find('p.costDiff');

    // Update Quantity
    var onHandQty = parseInt($onHandQty.text(),10);
    if(type == 1)
    {
        var difference =  onHandQty + parseInt($adjQty.val());
    }
    else if(type==0)
    {
        var difference = onHandQty - parseInt($adjQty.val());
    }

    $qtyDiff.text(difference);

    // Update Cost
    var currentCost = $currentCost.text();
    var difference = $newCost.val() - currentCost;
    $costDiff.text(difference);
}
```

I haven't tested the above code, but hopefully it helps you head in the right direction.

Comment: It works Perfectly sir @Rajeev Goel, THank you very much for the help. I did not even change a bit of your code, you are truly a genius sir. thanks a lot :)